# Boto3 Custom waiter rejected for not having a resource permission

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to create a custom waiter to resume a boto3 script when an rds db cluster is restored to a point in time. (I'm trying to adapt this methodology to my needs: https://medium.com/@Kentzo/customizing-botocore-waiters-83badbfd6399) Aside from the thin documentation on custom waiters this seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm having a permissions issue. The EC2 container where I'm running the script has permissions to run `rds:DescribeDBClusters` and I can make use of the permission in the script like so:

```
# Check on the cluster
response = rds.describe_db_clusters(
    DBClusterIdentifier=db_cluster_identifier,
)
status = response['DBClusters'][0]['Status']
print(status)
available
```

But when I set up a custom waiter to monitor this I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter DbClusterRestored failed: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/OrgIamRole/i-1234567890abcdef is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBClusters
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I don't understand why the waiter is missing permissions to do something that the script that created the waiter is allowed to do.

The container permissions look like this:

```
"OrgIamPolicy": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
  "Properties": {
    "PolicyName": "OrgIamPolicy",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Ref": "OrgIamRole"
      }
    ],
    "PolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
            "rds:DescribeDBClusters"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my code for restoring the cluster and setting up the waiter:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import os
import subprocess


rds = boto3.client('rds')

db_cluster_target_instance = 'orgstagingrdsinstance'
db_instance_identifier = 'backupinstance'
db_instance_class = 'db.t2.medium'
target_db_cluster_identifier = "org-backup-cluster"
source_db_cluster_identifier = "org-staging-rds-cluster"


# Create the cluster
response = rds.restore_db_cluster_to_point_in_time(
  DBClusterIdentifier=target_db_cluster_identifier,
  RestoreType='copy-on-write',
  SourceDBClusterIdentifier=source_db_cluster_identifier,
  UseLatestRestorableTime=True
)


# Check on the cluster
response = rds.describe_db_clusters(
    DBClusterIdentifier=db_cluster_identifier,
)
status = response['DBClusters'][0]['Status']
print(status)


# Create waiter
delay = 10
max_attempts = 30
waiter_name = "DbClusterRestored"

model = botocore.waiter.WaiterModel({
  "version": 2,
  "waiters": {
    "DbClusterRestored": {
      "operation": "DescribeDBClusters",
      "delay": delay,
      "maxAttempts": max_attempts,
      "acceptors": [
        {
          "matcher": "pathAll",
          "expected": "available",
          "state": "success",
          "argument": "DBClusters[].Status"
        },
        {
          "matcher": "pathAll",
          "expected": "deleting",
          "state": "failure",
          "argument": "DBClusters[].Status"
        },
        {
          "matcher": "pathAll",
          "expected": "creating",
          "state": "failure",
          "argument": "DBClusters[].Status"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})

waiter = botocore.waiter.create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, model, rds)
waiter.wait()
```

Obviously I have this code trimmed and I have obfuscated personal data. Sorry for any errors this might have introduced.

Any help you might give is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the answer to this seems to be pretty simple. The issue is with the scope of the request. The user has permission to run this on the following resource:

```
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:*"
]
```

When I ran

```
response = rds.describe_db_clusters(
    DBClusterIdentifier=db_cluster_identifier,
)
```

I was constraining the scope to a cluster that was in `arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:*`. When I ran

```
waiter = botocore.waiter.create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, model, rds)
waiter.wait()
```

I was not passing in that constraint. What I needed to run was

```
waiter = botocore.waiter.create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, model, rds)
waiter.wait(DBClusterIdentifier=db_cluster_identifier)
```

This passed the necessary constraint in and made sure that the permission scope matched the request.

I hope this helps someone in a similar situation.